# What does r() function mean in the return value of SymPy's dsolve?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, numerical-methods, ode

I want to evaluate the value of `phi(+oo)`
where `phi(xi)` is the solution of ODE

```
Eq(Derivative(phi(xi), (xi, 2)), (-K + xi**2)*phi(xi))
```

and `K` is a known real variable.
By `dsolve`, I got the solution:

```
Eq(phi(xi), -K*xi**5*r(3)/20 + C2*(K**2*xi**4/24 - K*xi**2/2 + xi**4/12 + 1) + C1*xi*(xi**4/20 + 1) + O(xi**6))
```

with an unknown function `r()` in the first term on the right-hand side.
Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy
from sympy import I, pi, oo

sympy.init_printing()

def apply_ics(sol, ics, x, known_params):
    """
    Apply the initial conditions (ics), given as a dictionary on
    the form ics = {y(0): y0, y(x).diff(x).subs(x, 0): yp0, ...},
    to the solution of the ODE with independent variable x.
    The undetermined integration constants C1, C2, ... are extracted
    from the free symbols of the ODE solution, excluding symbols in
    the known_params list.
    """

    free_params = sol.free_symbols - set(known_params)
    eqs = [(sol.lhs.diff(x, n) - sol.rhs.diff(x, n)).subs(x, 0).subs(ics)
            for n in range(len(ics))]
    sol_params = sympy.solve(eqs, free_params)

    return sol.subs(sol_params)

K = sympy.Symbol('K', positive = True)
xi = sympy.Symbol('xi',real = True)
phi = sympy.Function('phi')
ode = sympy.Eq( phi(xi).diff(xi, 2), (xi**2-K)*phi(xi))

ode_sol = sympy.dsolve(ode)
ics = { phi(0):1, phi(xi).diff(xi).subs(xi,0): 0}
phi_xi_sol = apply_ics(ode_sol, ics, xi, [K])
```

Where `ode_sol` is the solution, `phi_xi_sol` is the solution after initial conditions are applied.
Since `r()` is undefined in NumPy I can't evaluate the results by

```
for g in [0.9, 0.95, 1, 1.05, 1.2]:
    phi_xi = sympy.lambdify(xi, phi_xi_sol.rhs.subs({K:g}), 'numpy')
```

Does anyone know what this function `r()` mean and how should I deal with it?

Comment: With enough `symbols` commands I was able recreate your solution.  To proceed further you/we need to study the `dsolve` docs - possibly adding one or more parameters.

Comment: thank you, @hpaulj. Generally, when solving a second-order ODE only two initial/boundary are need to defined the unknown parameters. But after I applied them (see the added code), function r() still exist in "phi_xi_sol" I got.

Comment: Did you use the most recent sympy version? The solution in the second formula looks mathematically wrong, the first term should belong to the odd-powers basis solution with coefficient C1, it seems that the solution process was prematurely ended.

Comment: Checked with sympy 1.5.1, this has the same result.

Comment: Still the same with sympy 1.7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As visible in the form of the result, the solver falls back to a power series solution (instead of searching the solution in terms of parabolic cylinder functions as WolframAlpha does).

So let's set `phi(xi)=sum a[k]*xi^k` leading to the coefficient equations (using `a[k]=0` for `k<0`)

```
(k+2)(k+1)a[k+2] = -K*a[k] + a[k-2]

a[0] = C2  
a[1] = C1  
a[2] = -K/2*C2
a[3] = -K/6*C1
a[4] = (K^2/2 + 1)/12*C2
a[5] = (K^2/6 + 1)/20*C1
```

Inserting that the the power series solution should have been

```
C2*(1-K/2*xi**2+(K**2/24+1/12)*xi**4) + C1*xi*(1-K/6*xi**2+(K/120+1/20)*xi**4) + O(xi**6)
```

Comparing with the sympy solution, all terms containing both `C1` and `K` are missing, especially the missing degree 3 term is not explainable. It seems that the solution process was prematurely ended, or some equation transformation was not correctly reversed.

Please note that the ODE solver routines in sympy are experimental and rudimentary. Also, the power series solution gives only valid information for small values of `xi`, there is no way to derive any exact value for the limit at `+oo`.

Answer (score 0):

The `sol_params` is a list containing a single dictionary. Passing that dictionary instead of the list gives the solution `phi_xi_sol` without the `r(3)`:

```
Eq(rho(s), (-K*s**2/2 + s**2*xi**2/2 + 1)*(-6*rho(s) + 6*C2*s - C2*K*s**3 + O(s**5))/
            (3*(K*s**2 - 2)) + C2*(-K*s**3/6 + s**3*xi**2/6 + s) + O(s**5))
```