# Can we prioritise SymPy over SciPy while solving well posed differential equations?

Tags: python, sympy, differential-equations

Till now, I haven't faced any issue while solving well-posed differential equations problems using sympy only in python such as

1. Solving a second order linear differential equation:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import dsolve, symbols, Function, Eq

t= symbols('t')
x= symbols('x',cls=Function)

deq =Eq(x(t).diff(t,t)+2*t**2*x(t).diff(t)+x(t),0)
sol =dsolve(deq, x(t))
print(sol)
```

2. Solving an initial-valued problem:

```
from sympy import dsolve, symbols, Function, Eq, pprint

t = symbols('t')
x = symbols('x', cls = Function)

deq = Eq(x(t).diff(t)+t*x(t), t**3)
sol = dsolve(deq, n=8, ics={x(0):1})
pprint(sol)
```

3. Solving a system of differential equations:

```
from sympy import dsolve, Eq, Function, symbols

t= symbols('t')
x= symbols('x',cls=Function)
y = symbols('y',cls=Function)

deq = (Eq(x(t).diff(t),x(t)*y(t)*sin(t)),Eq(y(t).diff(t),y(t)*2*sin(t)))
sol  = dsolve(deq1, [x(t),y(t)])
print(sol)
```

4. Solving a differential equation and plotting a particular integral curve:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sympy import dsolve, Eq, symbols, Function
import numpy as np

t = symbols('t')
x = symbols('x', cls=Function)

deqn4 = Eq(2*(t-1)*x(t).diff(t),3*t**2+4*t+2)
sol4 = dsolve(deqn4, x(t))
print(sol4)

t = np.arange(-2.2,2.2,.2)
x = np.arange(-2,4.2,.2)
T, X = np.meshgrid(t,x)
Z = X**2 -2*X -T**3 -2*T**2 -2*T

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
CS = ax.contour(T, X,Z, [3])
```

I know that scipy is more flexible than the sympy, but results of sympy looks more fascinating as per my tittle experience of solving dynamical system problems using python.

Comment: Why do you consider scipy to be more flexible than sympy? They are complementary in a lot of ways but they have different use cases.

Comment: Because scipy covers numercal solution of the differential equation as well and it looks easy to plot the corresponding integral curve.

Comment: Less ODE have symbolic solutions, not all integration tricks are implemented in sympy, and some solver routines of sympy are simply wrong, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62981132/what-does-r-function-mean-in-the-return-value-of-sympys-dsolve. The scipy solvers have no such errors, they only have the problem that they are glacially slow compared with properly compiled versions of the same problems.

Comment: Thanks. Yea, I realized that after solving few more problems. I have to be more attentive by observing side information such as singularity of vector field, symmetry etc.