# Sympy simple second order ode

Tags: python, sympy, ode, symbolic-math

I want to perform ode with Sympy.

If I start with a simple one, such as, f''(x) = f(x), `dsolve` works fine

```py
import sympy as sym

z = sym.symbols('z', real=True) 
Phi = sym.Function('Phi')(z)
Phi_ = sym.Derivative(Phi,z)
Phi__ = sym.Derivative(Phi_,z)

Eqn1 = sym.Eq(Phi__, Phi) # f'' = f

sol1 = sym.dsolve(Eqn1) # Find solution
```

However, I try this ode f''(x) = exp(f(x)) (The solution can be check with [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%27%27%28x%29%3Dexp%28f%28x%29%29).)

```py
Eqn2 = sym.Eq(Phi__, sym.exp(Phi))  # f'' = exp (f)
sol2 = sym.dsolve(Eqn2) # ERROR
```

I have an error:

```
NotImplementedError: solve: Cannot solve -exp(Phi(z)) + Derivative(Phi(z), (z, 2))
```

Is this a limitation of Sympy? Should I use another function?

Comment: It is what the error says, a method for this kind of problem is not implemented. `dsolve` is incomplete and still has errors, see for instance the strange result in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62981132

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will try to work on Mathematica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what version of SymPy you are using but I'm using 1.9 and I just checked all versions back to 1.2 and this ODE is always solved:

```
In [1]: import sympy as sym
   ...: 
   ...: z = sym.symbols('z', real=True)
   ...: Phi = sym.Function('Phi')(z)
   ...: Phi_ = sym.Derivative(Phi,z)
   ...: Phi__ = sym.Derivative(Phi_,z)
   ...: 
   ...: Eqn1 = sym.Eq(Phi__, Phi) # f'' = f
   ...: 
   ...: sol1 = sym.dsolve(Eqn1) # Find solution

In [2]: sol1
Out[2]: 
           -z       z
Φ(z) = C₁⋅ℯ   + C₂⋅ℯ
```

Comment: You somehow missed the second ODE example that produces the error, `f''(x) = exp(f(x))`.

Comment: This ode works fine for me. It is when I want to solve the second ode ```sym.Eq(Phi__, sym.exp(Phi))  # f'' = exp (f)``` that I have an error.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the version 1.6.2 (Aug 2020). After an update to the **version 1.9** (Oct 2021), I finally can solved the second ode `f'' = exp(f)`. However, the solver is really slow.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).