# Strange r appears in dsolve output using Sympy

Tags: python, sympy, differential-equations

I'm interested in solving the following differential equation:

```
eqn = 4.0*N*sqrt(N - 1)*rho(s) + (4*s**2*(N - 1) + (N - 2*s*(N - 1))**2)*Derivative(rho(s), (s, 2))
```

I tried using dsolve from Sympy:

```
dsolve(eqn,rho(s), n=5)
```

which gave the following output:

```
Eq(rho(s), -1.33333333333333*s**3*r(2.0)/N + 1.33333333333333*s**3*r(2.0) + C2*(1 - 2.0*s**2*sqrt(N - 1.0)/N) + C1*s*(1.0 - 0.666666666666667*s**2*sqrt(N - 1.0)/N) + O(s**5))
```

What is this strange "r(2.0)"? I tried searching, but failed to find anything useful.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This appears to have the same error source as the problem described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62981132/what-does-r-function-mean, only that there it was `r(3)` that turned up unexpectedly.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Best to report to GitHub: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues

Comment: I have reported it, https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/22525. This is not something I have done before, so I hope it's ok!

Comment: Thanks for the report (here and there). In the current development version your original expression should now work (and it was added as a test).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The presence of the Floats is a clue that something might be wrong with the input (inasmuch as it will not give the desired output). If you change your `4.0` to `4` then you will not have the recurrence functions used to solve the equation left in the solution. If you look at the `finaldict` value in the `ode_2nd_power_series_ordinary` it looks like this with your `4.0`:

```
{r(2): -2.0*sqrt(N - 1.0)*r(0)/N, 
 r(3): 0.666666666666667*(2*N*r(2.0) - sqrt(N - 1.0)*r(1) - 2*r(2.0))/N}
```

instead of

```
{r(2): -2*sqrt(N - 1)*r(0)/N, 
 r(3): 2*(-4*sqrt(N - 1)*r(0) - sqrt(N - 1)*r(1) + 4*sqrt(N - 1)*r(0)/N)/(3*N)}
```

The solution using `4` instead of `4.0` has no `r(2.0)`:

```
Eq(rho(s), 
    C2*(s - 2*s**3*sqrt(N - 1)/(3*N)) + 
    C1*(1 - 8*s**3*sqrt(N - 1)/(3*N) - 
    2*s**2*sqrt(N - 1)/N + 8*s**3*sqrt(N - 1)/(3*N**2)) + O(s**5))
```

Comment: Thank you! I was debugging the code and noticed there are two calls to the function solve in ode_2nd_power_series_ordinary that turn the indices into Floats and prohibit the substitution of r from working. Interestingly setting rational=False in the calls of solve eliminates r from the final answer, at the cost of making all coefficients Floats. I'm still trying to understand how this is possible!

Comment: Better yet, adding the flag ```rational=True``` solves the problem and yields rational coefficients. I do not understand how this is possible, given that this should be the default behaviour of the function.

Comment: I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/22524)

Comment: Oops, I opened one as well at  https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/22525. What should I do? Close that one?